# Parse unstructured text for dictionary terms to include a link to term

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working on a django project, and have a model that has a list of `things`.  Throughout the site, I may have unstructured text entered in other models.  On display of a page, I would like to parse the unstructured text, for any reference to `thing.slug`, and include a link to `thing.get_absolute_url`.

I would assume an app would need to consist of a custom templatetag, that parses `object.text`, which uses something like a regular expression parser to match any `thing.slug` terms from a dictionary of all `things`.

Take for example:

> I have thingA and thingB, but would like thingC.

Would be modified to:

```
I have <a href="/things/a">thingA</a> and <a href="/things/b">thingB</a>, but would like <a href="/things/c">thingC</a>.
```

If there is a django app that already does this, great!  Otherwise, any advice on how best to accomplish this is appreciated.  I'm up for other suggestions such as jquery as well, even though I'm not as familiar with it.

Comment: How does the matching go exactly? You say `thingA` should be converted to `/things/a`, but should `thingamajiggy` be converted to `thing/amajiggy`? Is it CamelCase, so that `thingThatIWant` becomes `/things/that/i/want`?

Comment: If you're familiar with django, my model has fields for `title` and `slug`, so the slug would be what the urlpattern matches.

Comment: @erikankrom: It would help to update your question, showing precisely how `thingamajiggy` and `thingThatIWant` should be handled.  It helps to include the relevant parts of your model in the question, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urls = dict((thing.slug, thing.get_absolute_url) for thing in things)
for word in object.text.split():
  if word in urls:
     result.append('<a href="'+urls[words]+'">'+word+'</a> ')
  else
     result.append(word+' ')
```

Comment: I like this method.  In the model, post_save, I can parse the object.text into object.html, via celery probably.

Answer (score 1):

The *re* module has a *sub()* function that is designed for this kind of search and replace.

Search for the pattern that distinguishes "things" from the rest of the unstructured text and construct the appropriate substitution string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'I have thing.slug and thing.foo, but would like thing.foo'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)\.(\w+)', r'<a href="/\1/\2">\1.\2</a>', s)
'I have <a href="/thing/slug">thing.slug</a> and <a href="/thing/foo">thing.foo</a>, but would like <a href="/thing/foo">thing.foo</a>'
```

This is more reliable (less error-prone) is you make the pattern for "things" more distinctive:

```
>>> s = 'I have {thing.slug} and {thing.foo}, but would like {thing.foo}'
>>> re.sub(r'{(\w+)\.(\w+)}', r'<a href="/\1/\2">\1.\2</a>', s)
'I have <a href="/thing/slug">thing.slug</a> and <a href="/thing/foo">thing.foo</a>, but would like <a href="/thing/foo">thing.foo</a>'
```